# What is the correct way of dealing with a django model that is in many categories or sub categories

Tags: django, django-models, categories, django-mptt

I'm unsure of the best way to design my models for this task.  Searching around suggests that I need to use something like Django-MPTT.

I am creating a listings application where any 'item' can be listed under multiple categories. From any category I will need to be able to query for 'items' that match.

An example should illustrate what I want a little better.

I have one **Item1** that is to be assigned to two sub categories.

```
TopLevel1
   --- Sublevel1
   --- Sublevel2
           -----> Item1

TopLevel1
   --- Sublevel1
          ------> Item1
   --- Sublevel2
```

Can anyone suggest how the models/relationships should be constructed?  My current implementation

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)


class Item(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Does not feel like the correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I see it...

Your models seem close, a m2m seems appropriate, but your diagram would look more like:

```
Item1
    ---> TopLevel1 (accessed through `categories`)
        ---> SubLevel1 (accessed through `Category.children`, see below)
        ---> SubLevel2 (accessed through `Category.children`, see below)
```

and your models would look more like

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128) # `blank` is false by default
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children') # by giving this field a nice `related_name`, we can easily access the linked categories

class Item(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.TextField() # `null` and `blank` are false by default
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True, related_name='items')
```

Now, if you have an item and would like to get it's top-level categories, you can loop through `item.categories.all()`

```
{% for category in item.categories.all %}
    Top Level: {{ category.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

and to access the sub-level categories, you loop through `children.all()` in each `category`

```
{% for category in item.categories.all %}
    Top Level: {{ category.name }}
    {% for child in category.children.all %}
        Sub Level: {{ child.name }}
        Parent: {{ child.parent.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

you can also get all of the items in a category

```
{% for item in category.items.all %}
    Item: {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

or if you are in a top-level category

```
{% for child in category.children.all %}
    {{ child.name }}
    {% for item in child.items.all %}
        Item: {{ item.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And with

```
category_one = Category.objects.create('category one')
category_two = Category.objects.create('category two')
item_one = Item.objects.create('item one')
```

You can [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) a `Category` through the [related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) `categories` on `Item`

```
item_one.categories.add(category_one, category_two)
```

or you can [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) an `Item` through the related manager `items` on `Category`

```
category_one.items.add(item_one)
```

Comment: Excellent thanks.  I will read this in more detail and try it later.  It seems exactly what I want.  Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I want.  I am experimenting with this in some tests.  For efficiency, should the Category Model subclass MPTTModel and the ForeignKeyField be a TreeForeignKey?

Comment: No problem. I'm unblocked enough now and will leave the mptt work until its worth looking at optimisations. I can probably just use a cache to avoid performance issues in this instance anyway.